# Ignore nan cells when performing a pandas lambda map

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and mapping dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
     'Name': ['Jim','Jack','Jim','Jack','Jim','Jack','Mick','Mick'],
    'Day':['Mon','Tue','Mon',np.nan,'Sat','Sun','Tue',np.nan],
    'Value':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80],
    })


values = {
    'Mon':['Monday','M']
    ,'Tue':['Tuesday','T']
    ,'Wed':['Wednesday','W']
    ,'Thu':['Thursday','TH']
    ,'Fri':['Friday','F']
    ,'Sat':['Saturday','SA']
    ,'Sun':['Sunday','SU']
}
df
```

[image]

as you can see there are some `nan` values in the `Day` column.

I am trying to add the following column:

```
df['Day_Name'] = 'The name of the person is ' + df['Name'] + ' and the day of the week is ' + df['Day'].map(lambda x: values[x][0])
```

but i am getting a `nan` error due to the 2 nan cells present. Is there anything i can skip over the blank cells (and return blank) for those particular rows in the new `df['Day_Name']` column? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dict.get` with specify list with empty space for possible after selection first value get empty value:

```
s = df['Day'].map(lambda x: values.get(x, [''])[0])
df['Day_Name'] = 'The name of the person is ' + df['Name'] + ' and the day of the week is ' + s
print (df)
   Name  Day  Value                                           Day_Name
0   Jim  Mon     10  The name of the person is Jim and the day of t...
1  Jack  Tue     20  The name of the person is Jack and the day of ...
2   Jim  Mon     30  The name of the person is Jim and the day of t...
3  Jack  NaN     40  The name of the person is Jack and the day of ...
4   Jim  Sat     50  The name of the person is Jim and the day of t...
5  Jack  Sun     60  The name of the person is Jack and the day of ...
6  Mick  Tue     70  The name of the person is Mick and the day of ...
7  Mick  NaN     80  The name of the person is Mick and the day of ...
```